# Dynamic add plus to each row in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic2 project which pulls data from and API and displays content of the API to the user which works fine. 
But the challenge is i want number the rows in the view as the user scroll down . For example if the API return data of lenght 40, i want to number the rows from 1 to 40.

JS

```
  ionViewDidLoad(){
    let loader = this.LoadingController.create({
      content: 'Loading Test'
    });
    loader.present().then(()=>{
      this.http
        .get('http://localhost/scripts/items.php')
        .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            this.store= data;

            for(var i=1;i<data.length;i++) {
              this.count = i++;

          }
        });
      loader.dismiss();
    });
```

HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of store">
    {{count}}. {{item.Item_Name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use index provided by `*ngFor` directive:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of store; let i = index">
    {{i + 1}}. {{item.Item_Name}}
</div>
```

More info about this in angular docs:

https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables

There is also a bit different syntax, which is probably now recommended (depends on what version you use, but the first one is still working I think):

```
*ngFor="let item of store; index as i"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to add indicies to the data in `http.get` callback:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i].index = i + 1;
}
```

And then:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of store">
   {{item.index}}. {{item.Item_Name}}
</div>
```

This could be helpful if you need the index not only in the view. In other case I would recommend to use @martin-adámek [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47002784/3211932).